# Como os falantes nativos de português pronunciam «apple» e «rugby»

Tags: pronúncia, estrangeirismos

As palavras inglesas *apple* e *rugby* entraram na língua portuguesa. *Rugby* até já gerou dois aportuguesamentos: *rúgbi* no Brasil e *râguebi* em Portugal. O que é curioso é que a pronúncia que eu ouço destas palavras em Portugal tem pouco a ver com a pronúncia nativa, e estou curioso em saber se o mesmo acontece  no Brasil, e em África se alguém souber.

Em Portugal ouço *apple* pronunciado /'ɐj.pəl/; ou seja o ***a*** é pronunciado como o ***a*** da palavra inglesa ***a***pe ou *K**a**te*, ou o ***ai*** de *em**ai**l*. E era assim que eu pronunciava até um inglês me corrigir, pois os nativos pronunciam esse ***a*** algures entre o nosso ***á*** e o nosso ***é***, mas próximo do ***á***. Podem ouvir [aqui no Forvo](http://pt.forvo.com/word/apple/#en) oito nativos a pronunciar *apple*. O natural seria nós pronunciarmos ***á*** ou ***é*** (os portugueses tendem para o ***é***); é curioso que tenhamos mudado o som para /ɐj/.

A pronúncia que me é mais familiar de *rugby* em Portugal é /ˈʀɐj.ɡbi/. Aqui é o ***u*** que é pronunciado como o ***ai*** de mail, enquanto os nativos o pronunciam basicamente como o nosso ***â***; o [Forvo](http://pt.forvo.com/word/pt/rugby/#en) tem dez pessoas a pronunciar *rugby*. É curioso que a grafia do aportuguesamento *râguebi* tenta reproduzir a pronúncia inglesa, mas depois nós pronunciamos aquilo doutra maneira. E esta pronúncia bastarda está mesmo consagrada na [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/r%C3%A2guebi).

O [Michaelis indica *rúgbi*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=r%FAgbi) pronunciado como se escreve.

Portanto eu gostaria de saber como é pronunciado *apple* no Brasil; não sei se no fora da zona de Lisboa a pronúncia também é /'ɐj.pəl/; e para *rugby*, qual é a forma escrita e a pronúncia usada no Brasil.

Comment: E «tômb ráider» (túmb reider), «xis bócs» (écs bócs), etc... os tugas são peritos em amachucar as palavras. Sabias que «naifa» vem do inglês *knife*?

Comment: @ANeves Sim, sim, *tomb ráider* é outra. E no outro dia ouvi um crítico de cinema falar da Káira Knightley e do Alan Târing. O que é curioso é que nós vemos filmes no original (legendados, dublados) mas não registamos a pronúncia dos nativos.

Comment: /'ɐj.pəl/? Ia jurar que a primeira sílaba se dizia com o _a_ aberto português.

Comment: @Artefacto No original? No original é basicamente isso. Mas eu ouço constantemente os portugueses a pronunciar /'ɐj.pəl/. Mesmo pessoal instruído.

Comment: Queria dizer que _em Portugal_ ouço com _a_ aberto (por exemplo, na comunicação social). Consegues arranjar provas de que de facto se diz "ei"?

Comment: Eu ouço aqui no Brasil algo como épol e também esta forma que colocou na sua pergunta. Rúgbi não sei te dizer, a única certeza que o R sai como Rua, o R do inglês não é comum de se ouvir, soa muito pedante.

Comment: Repara nesta peça: http://tviplayer.iol.pt/video/56f06caf0cf20176bcffac76 . A pronúncia portuguesa é com _a_ aberto. E eu não estive a escolher os morangos, este foi o primeiro resultado que encontrei.

Comment: @Artefacto Na minha experiência, muitos portugueses (mas não a maioria) dizem /'ɐj.pəl/. Mas como tu dizes, duvido que o pronunciem assim na comunicação social; seria uma argolada ridícula.

Comment: Aqui no Brasil, o correto é "épol", mas há algumas pessoas que falam "êipol". Quanto a rugby, é pronunciado "râgbi", e "rúgbi" por outros.

Answer (score 2):

Bem, a "apple" que chegou ao Brasil foi a empresa que projeta e vende tocadores de áudio digital. A fruta continua entrando aqui sob o nome de "maçã".  Essa "apple" que produz o Ipod tem o **"a"** mais frequentemente pronunciado da mesma forma que o **"e"** de **"festa"**. Sendo uma aquisição recente da língua portuguesa, a pronuncia varia e também ouvimos a mesma vogal pronunciada como o **"a"** de **"fado"** ou ainda como o **"æ"** britânico ou o americano.

Já a palavra **"rugby"** é muito pouco usada pelos brasileiros. O jogo era praticamente desconhecido até que houve a escolha do Rio de Janeiro como cidade sede dos próximos Jogos Olímpicos.  Como país patrocinador, o Brasil teve que formar uma seleção para um jogo que os brasileiros mal conhecem. Não ouço a palavra com frequência mas as poucas vezes que ouvi a pronuncia foi a mesma que a dos Ingleses. Se eu tiver que pronunciá-la em português, direi **[rʌgbɪ]**

Answer (score 0):

"Apple" a gente tenta imitar a pronúncia do inglês, uma vez que se trata de nome próprio. Vira alguma coisa como [ɛpow]. Ugh. Rúgbi seria ['ʁuɡbi] ou talvez ['ʁuɡibi], dependendo da formalidade do contexto. E o /i/ final, como sempre, vira /j/ sempre que seguido de vogal: "Rúgbi, um futebol que se joga com as mãos" - ['ʁuɡbjũfute'bɔɫ] / ['ʁuɡibjũfutʃi'bɔw].

(Deveria haver um "n" sobrescrito depois do /ũ/, mas não consigo fazer o efeito aqui.)